# How to align x-axis labels horizontally

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

In the following plot, I want the 0 in the x-axis labels on the same level with all of the other x-axis-labels. How do I achieve this ? Here is the important part of my code:

```
for i, h3 in enumerate(np.linspace(-0.1, 0.1, 3)):
for j, h4 in enumerate(np.linspace(-0.1, 0.1, 3)):
    gh_params[3] = h3
    gh_params[4] = h4
    gauss_vals = gauss(x, *gauss_params)
    gh_vals = gauss_hermite(x, *gh_params)
    gausshermite_color = 'mediumblue'
    gauss_color = 'darkorange'
    axs[i, j].plot(x, gh_vals, color=gausshermite_color, linewidth=0.6, label=r'$\mathscr{L}_{GH}$')
    axs[i,j].plot(x, gauss_vals, color=gauss_color, linewidth=0.6, label=r'$\mathscr{L}_G$')
    axs[i,j].set_xlim([-5*sigma, 5*sigma])
    axs[i,j].set_ylim([-0.1, 1.4*np.max(gauss_vals)])

    # adjust ticks of the axes
    axs[i,j].xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))
    axs[i,j].yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(0.2))
    axs[i,j].xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(2/3))
    axs[i,j].yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.2/3))
    axs[i,j].tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labeltop=False, direction='in', length=2, width=0.2,
                   bottom=True, top=True, labelbottom=True, left=True, right=True, labelleft=True, labelright=False)
```

With the following plot, where you can see that the 0 is too high. [image]

I am using the font:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-bright')
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{mathrsfs}')
tex_fonts = {
    # Use LaTeX to write all text
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "serif",
    "axes.labelsize": 10.95,
    "font.size": 10.95,
    "legend.fontsize": 10.95,
    "xtick.labelsize": 10.95,
    "ytick.labelsize": 10.95,
    "axes.linewidth":10.95/14,
    "grid.linewidth":0.1}
plt.rcParams.update(tex_fonts)
```

Comment: It's not just the 0. All the non-negatives are higher than the negatives. What font are you using?

Comment: I added the font that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved using the following code:

```
        # Set the number of decimal places to display
    decimal_places = 0

    # Define the x-axis tick positions and labels
    x_ticks = np.array([-4,-2,0,2,4])
    x_tick_labels = [f"{x:.{decimal_places}f}" for x in x_ticks]

    # Create the FixedLocator and FixedFormatter objects
    x_tick_locator = FixedLocator(x_ticks)
    x_tick_formatter = FixedFormatter(x_tick_labels)

    # Set the x-axis tick locator and formatter
    axs[i, j].xaxis.set_major_locator(x_tick_locator)
    axs[i, j].xaxis.set_major_formatter(x_tick_formatter)
```